# Store SSRS Report export directly to database

Tags: ssrs

As a requirement, I have to check for a certain condition on some data in the database, if the condition is true, then I have to create a pdf report and store it on a table.

I have everything set up as a T-SQL SP except the pdf report part.

Is there anyway to execute an SSRS Report, export it to PDF and store the pdf in a varbinary column directly from T-SQL ?

Otherwise the only solution would be creating a Windows Service to do this (I Know how to do this but the T-SQL way would give me more flexibility).

Thanks!

Comment: There are code examples around (http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2007/04/29/112094.aspx) that show you how to render a report directly to a PDF.  I imagine you could use that, store the file in a temp location and then insert the the file into the DB.

Comment: I Know how to do that, i wanted to know if i could do it using t-sql for it's flexibility. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to write any sort of code in .Net and connect it into SQL Server.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19954/Execute-NET-Code-under-SQL-Server-2005 for an example.